# facing issue using $scope and $rootscope

Tags: angularjs

I am facing issue to print text using angualrjs $scope and $rootscope.
Please find the code below and let me know where i did mistake.

```
<body ng-app="x">

        <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
            Hello {{name2}}
        </div>

        <div ng-controller="ctrl2">
            Hi {{name1}} How {{name3}}
        </div>

        <script>

            var app= angulr.module("x",[]);

            app.controller("ctrl1" ,['$scope', '$rootScope',function($scope, $rootscope){

                $scope.name2 = "Sir";
                $rootscope.name3 = "are you!";
            }]);

            app.controller("ctrl2", function($scope){

                $scope.name1 = "madam";
            });

        </script>

    </body>
```

Comment: One key point - Please make your `$rootScope` lighter as much as you can :)

Comment: Why this question is close. is this community does not support to post the issues when developer develop code.am i correct ?

Comment: @vineet :- Please elaborate the point. why to make $rootscope lighter ?

Comment: Of course, global state sucks and you should use $rootScope sparingly, like you would (hopefully) use with global variables in any language. In particular, don't use it for code, only data. If you're tempted to put a function on $rootScope, it's almost always better to put it in a service that can be injected where it's needed, and more easily tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run the following code. Problem solved. You spelled angular incorrectly and you dont need to put scope and rootScope in bracket in ctrl1 in controller. Also it is rootScope and not rootscope (check the capital S)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="x">

        <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
            Hello {{name2}}
        </div>

        <div ng-controller="ctrl2">
            Hi {{name1}} How {{name3}}
        </div>

        <script>

            var app= angular.module("x",[]);

            app.controller("ctrl1" ,function($scope, $rootScope){

                $scope.name2 = "Sir";
                $rootScope.name3 = "are you!";
            });

            app.controller("ctrl2", function($scope){

                $scope.name1 = "madam";
            });

        </script>

    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks Pritesh. Typo error. And i made $rootscope , "s" is lowercase is also working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="x">

<div ng-controller="ctrl1">
        Hello {{name2}}
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="ctrl2">
        Hi {{name1}} How {{name3}}
    </div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('x', []);
 app.controller("ctrl1" ,['$scope', '$rootScope',function($scope, $rootscope){

            $scope.name2 = "Sir";
            $rootscope.name3 = "are you!";
        }]);
app.controller("ctrl2", function($scope){

            $scope.name1 = "madam";
        });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```